# How to test readonly property of Puppet type

Tags: ruby, rspec, puppet, ruby-1.8.7, rspec3

I have Puppet type defined like this:

```
Puppet::Type.newtype(:my_type) do
  newproperty(:id, :readonly => true) do
    desc "Some id."
  end
end
```

I want to ask how to test in rspecs that property :id is readonly?

```
describe Puppet::Type.type(:netapp_e_volume) do
  it 'should have readonly :id attribute' do
    # this part I don't have
  end
end
```

Comment: Is this a thing that happens? There does not seem to be precedent for using this syntax among Puppet's core types (anymore?)

Comment: From book "Puppet Types and Providers": "Certain attributes, such as UUIDs, can be queried from the system but cannot be updated. These attributes can be implemented as read-only properties so that puppet resource still returns their value when in‐ specting the system."

Comment: I'm aware that such things used to be documented, but I find no indication in the source that a) this is possible or easy to implement and b) that the syntax you are using is supported at all. So I guess the real question is how to mark a property as readonly in the first place, to which I have no answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of April of 2016 this is still not possible according to this Puppet Jira Ticket

https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-5624

The tickect is still in Unresolved state